# HP docking station suppresses video resolution

Tags: windows, resolution, docking-station, hp

I have a HP laptop and a DELL monitor (1900x1200). When I connect the monitor to the latop using a HDMI cable, Windows 10 offers me the 1900x1200 as recommended resolution.

Now I purchased a docking station (HP USB-C G5 dock) which allows all peripheral devices incl. monitor to be connected to it. It can then be connected to the laptop through a single USB-C cable. The monitor is connected now to the docking station using the same HDMI cable.

The proble I have is that in the Windows settings the optimal resolution of 1900x1200 is not listed. Instead Windows preselects 1680x1050.

Is there a was to force Windows to use 1900x1200 resolutions?

Comment: Does your laptop have USB-C alt mode (video)? If not then it's using DisplayLink (or similar technology) so 1) it may require proprietary drivers and/or 2) it may *not* support all resolutions.

Comment: Looks like you're pushing the limits of that dock at 1900x1200.  All the external ports have a signaling rate of up to 5Gbps.  1920x1080 has a range of between 4-8 Gbps.